# Extracting a function from a standard

Tags: functions, standard-deviation

I have a standard and I need create a function to resolve this, for example:

if my $X < 21$ my $Y$ will be $24$ else if my $x < 28$ my $y$ will be $32$ ...

How do I calculate a function for this?

Thanks all.

Comment: @Rasmus the standart is what i want, for example here x < 21 → y = 24 and (x+7) < (21+7) → y = (24+8) ...

Comment: You ask [if (x<21) y=24; else if (x<28) y=32;] but can y really only have these 2 values ? (and what if x>=28 ?)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni not, the y will vary between 17 values. and x between n values.

Comment: you could create an array of sorted (maximal x, corresponding y) (or two arrays) and parse it in a function with sequential or binary search (rather a question for stack overflow...). But the ifs could be faster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define the function in piecewise terms over its domain:

$$y=f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 24, & \mathrm{if}\ x < 21, \\
32, & \mathrm{if}\ 21 \le x < 28. \\
\end{array}\right.$$

As to whether there is a pattern herein, there is not enough information to decide.

Another way is to use *indicator functions*, which are defined as $$\mathbf{1}[\chi] = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1, & \mathrm{if}\ \chi\ \mathrm{is\ true}, \\
0, & \mathrm{if}\ \chi\ \mathrm{is\ false}.\end{array}\right.$$

Them you can write $$y=f(x) = 24\cdot\mathbf{1}[x < 21] + 32\cdot\mathbf{1}[21 \le x < 28] + \cdots$$

In programming, sometimes indicator functions are called "boolean variables" (where you might have to map $\mathrm{true} \mapsto 1$, $\mathrm{false} \mapsto 0$.)

Comment: Whoops! Misread it. Editing, thanks!

Comment: thanks, but I have 17 ifs in my real problem, and i'm implementing this in java, to do so is bad because wiil be 17 ifs in code, very bad, don't have a other way?

Comment: That is a programming question. There are likely many other ways to implement this using mathematical functions; however, you have given only a small subset of your problem. Furthermore, is the code really more readable if you implement a complicated mathematical function than using obvious heuristics? At any rate, I will edit my answer to specify another approach.

Comment: @EdGorcenski thanks for light I will in this way. really with the function had become less clear but will be faster and with a appropriate comment had been easy to understand.

Comment: @ademar: this should be asked on one of the programming sites. Anyways... (1) unless you have *good reason* to think that it's important for this function to be faster, you should stick to whatever is more clear. (2) you can do clever things with chained if's: you can write them in the order they're most likely to be satisfied, or nest them as a binary search, or other sorts of things. (3) You can encode the relevant data in other fashions, such as having an array of <upper bound, value> pairs, and searching the array for the appropriate value. (4) et cetera

Comment: @Hurkyl I agree but a simple function will can improve my solution, this type of question is necessarily mathematical because I wanted first a mathematical solution after implements in my programming language.

Comment: @ademar111190: you haven't given enough properties of your function for there to be a "mathematical solution". Besides, "mathematical solutions" aren't always good for computer (or other sorts of) calculation. The indicator function given in this answer **is** an implementation in a language -- worse, it's in a language that was meant for manipulation by mathematicians, not execution by computers.

Comment: @Hurkyl Indeed, but the indicator function method is probably the *easiest* and most straightforward way to implement the conditional approach. One could easily define an anonymous function and pass it a logical argument; heck, in C, you could use the ? operator straight-up.